# swift 3 textlabel text is true

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, textfield

This code is giving me an error here. Sorry I'm a newbie. I want to make an app, that if I type 'hi' into textfield it's going to give me a response 'hello' in a label.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {


    @IBAction func label(_ sender: Any) {

    }
    @IBAction func sendBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if label.text == "hi" {
            txtOutput.text = "hello!"
        }
    }
    @IBAction func txtOutput(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your error and what does it say?

Comment: hi, welcome to SO but I fear this might be a bit too broad for SO.... which is more of a QA site than a 'teach me how to code' :) maybe try on code review stack exchange or look at tutorials.

Comment: I CAN tell you that you miss 2 IBOutlet vars which you already use. then: all the rest is doable in IB.

Comment: Do you have an outlet for the Label? I agree with Daij-Djan - there are plenty of tutorials that walk through these types of apps, showing all the required steps and explaining the reason for each thing you're typing, dragging, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txtOutput` should be connected as `@IBOutlet` and not as a `@IBAction`

with `@IBAction` you only trigger some actions but you don't get a reference to the object

with `@IBOutlet` you get a reference to the object and can access the properties like `.text` of this object

Just be carefully when you drag the connections from IB to the code

for iOS your code should be look like (since you use `NSViewController` it should be the Cocoa object for it)

```
@IBOutlet var txtOutput: UILabel!
// or 
@IBOutlet weak var txtOutput: UILabel!
```

but dont just change the code. double check if this connection is also assigned at the Label in InterfaceBuilder

**Update**

now you can set the text with:

```
txtOutput.stringValue = "Hello"
```

Comment: Didn't fix my errors. Errors are Value of type Any() -> has no member txt and value of type NSTextField has no member txt. I changed  @IBAction func txtOutput(_ sender: Any) {

    }   to   (at)IBOutlet weak var txtOutput: NSTextField!

Comment: you should include your defailed error message in your inital question!

Comment: dont only change the code - also change the connections from interface builder

Comment: i added `txtOutput.stringValue = "Hello"` to the answer - there is a different way to set text on NSTextField than on UILabel

Comment: the easy way to drag it again into code as `IBOutlet` or check in the interface builder if you select your `NSTextField` and on the right side open the `connections inspector` if there is a connection.